# what is the equivalent of req.url from node.js in python

Tags: python, node.js, url

I am pretty good with node.js and i know there is a node.js function called `req.url`. I now trying to use a python script and want to use the equivalent of it. Does anyone know what it is?

EDIT:
here is an example of what i mean in node.js:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.url); //will return the current url
});
```

EDIT2:
I am using node.js to do the http requests and stuff. Here is an example.
node:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  const py = spawn('python', ['python.py']);
});
```

python:

```
url = '' #get url here 
print(url)
```

Comment: Did you mean the `url` property of `req` argument from the call back function such as `http.createServer(function(req, res) { ... });`?

Comment: depends on what library/framework you're using, but usually `path`

Comment: i am not using any framework

Comment: Then how are you handling http requests? What is your python? Can you show us the code?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I am using the `child_process` module in node.js to activate my python code. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use some sort of framework in order to do so since Python doesn't support that feature directly and it will be a pain to implement it from scratch. For example, with Flask you can get the request's url using the following approach

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    req_url = request.full_path
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```